# How do I access a javascript value across functions/variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, three small parts:

1) a MaxMind geo IP lookup that gets us the country code via the IP address:

```
var onSuccess = function(x){

var ip = x.traits.ip_address;
document.getElementById('ip_address').value = ip;

var country_code = x.country.iso_code;
document.getElementById('ip_country_code').value = country_code;

…

};
```

2) an array of country references with tax percent decimals:

```
// Array of values for tax rates
var tax_rates= new Array();
tax_rates["noteu"]=0.0;
tax_rates["ES"]=21.0;
tax_rates["AU"]=20.5;
tax_rates["BE"]=21.7;
…
```

3) a TaxPrice function that takes one of those decimals to calculating tax and then total payable in a subscription form. Notice the XXXXX:

```
function TaxPrice()
{
var taxprice=0;
XXXXX
return taxprice;
}
```

The `document.getElementById` bit in 1) can obviously update a hidden field or some other HTML element.

I know what to do with XXXXX if it's a manual drop down the user has to select.

But how do I get the tax decimal out of the array and into the TaxPrice function based on the IP address country code? (i.e. within the javascript, not updating an HTML element).

Happy New Year to all.

UPDATE: Just to be clear, I don't need to know how to get it into a drop down, I can do that already and in this use case, the user should not be allowed to choose his own tax country, it should be set automatically based on the IP address. So the non-code wording would go something like:

`taxprice EQUALS tax_rate.value ACCORDING TO ip_address_code`

Comment: Not what you're asking, but there's no point using an array if you aren't going to use numeric indices. An [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) would be better.

Comment: One way you can do it is to set a global `selectedCountryCode` variable inside your success callback, and reference `tax_rates[selectedCountryCode]` in your TaxPrice array (which should be an object, as nnnnnn pointed out)

Comment: you could set the values into local or session storage and then access them from any function or part of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks for your suggestions. Not sure if I understand how this is working exactly, but after some poking around, it now is. Compared to the code in the original question, I had to:

1) Add a global variable at the top, above everything else, unrelated to the IP lookup code (i.e. there is now no reference to `country_tax` within the IP `onSuccess` variable):

```
var country_tax;
```

2) Replace XXXXX in the TaxPrice function with:

```
var country_tax = document.getElementById("ip_country_code").value;
var taxprice = taxes_from_database[country_tax];
```

So the full TaxPrice function ends up as:

```
function TaxPrice() 
{
var taxprice = 0;
var country_tax = document.getElementById("ip_country_code").value;
var taxprice = tax_rates[country_tax];
return taxprice;
}
```

No need, it seems, for nested functions or closures or anything very complicated. It doesn't matter (to the code) if the tax_rates are set up as an array or an object, the outcome is the same, although I would like to understand why you recommend an object over an array in this case.

And—given TaxPrice gets the value from the form field and not from within the IP onSuccess function—I don't know why I need the global variable declaration at the top, if anyone wants to have a go at explaining that…

Comment: Well, this would work, but you kind of defeated your original purpose with this answer which was "within the javascript, not updating an HTML element". Also, this method is extremely susceptible to tampering, as someone can go in to the browser inspector and change the value of the ip_country_code element, and then your `TaxPrice()` function would read their value, rather than the correct value.

Comment: The reason for using an object over an array is because there are no associative arrays in JavaScript. Essentially what you are doing when you say `var tax_rates = new Array()` is creating an array **object**, and then assigning object properties dynamically by saying `tax_rates["foo"] = "bar"`. Now, by definition, an associative array is nothing more than a structure that holds key/value pairs, which is exactly what an object is in JavaScript. So, although using `new Array()` works, it is not intuitive and not how the JS array was designed to be used.

Comment: A good example of how *it works, but you're doing it wrong* is try doing the same thing with a string object. `var x = new String(); x["foo"] = "bar"; console.log(x.foo);` It will output "bar", but it it not how the string object was designed to be used. The same holds true with the Number object as well - `var y = new Number();`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like element properties?
    Mydiv.tax=taxvalue;
Properties of Elements are an elegant way of communicating between different functions. 
You can  assign any value to any element. 
You can retrieve the value from any function in JavaScript as long as the Basic element lives.

Comment: "within the javascript, not updating an HTML element"

Comment: Thank you Frank, but no, I know how to get it to the HTML but I need to know how to pass it to the other bit of the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to set a global `selectedCountryCode` variable inside your success callback, and reference `tax_rates[selectedCountryCode]` in your TaxPrice array (which should be an object, as nnnnnn pointed out)

```js
(function () {
  var selectedCountryCode = "";
  var onSuccess = function(x) {

    var ip = x.traits.ip_address;
    document.getElementById('ip_address').value = ip;

    selectedCountryCode = x.country.iso_code; // <-- Set selectedCountryCode for later use
    document.getElementById('ip_country_code').value = selectedCountryCode; // <-- Set dropdown value

  };

  document.getElementById("ip_country_code").addEventListener("change", function() {
    selectedCountryCode = this.value;
    console.log(TaxPrice());
  });

  // Object of values for tax rates
  var tax_rates = {};
  tax_rates["noteu"] = 0.0;
  tax_rates["ES"] = 21.0;
  tax_rates["AU"] = 20.5;
  tax_rates["BE"] = 21.7;


  function TaxPrice() {
    var taxprice = 0;
    taxprice = tax_rates[selectedCountryCode];
    return taxprice;
  }
})();
```

```html
Change Me: <select id="ip_country_code">
  <option value="noteu">noteu</option>
  <option value="ES">ES</option>
  <option value="AU">AU</option>
  <option value="BE">BE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks M, but I know how to do it with a manual select drop down already. I just need to pass the value inside the javascript. In this use case, the user should not be allowed to choose his own tax country, it should come automatically via the IP address lookup.

Comment: @MatthewBennett Yeah, I added that to your success function that you had defined. I just added the select dropdown functionality so you could see how it worked in a demo w/o having to fake an ajax call.

Comment: Ok, let me try, hang on.

Comment: Would all of the calculations that are dependent on TaxPrice also have to go inside the top function?

Comment: @MatthewBennett No, but they would have to be run **after** the onSuccess function runs, otherwise `TaxPrice()` would return undefined.

Comment: Hmmm, strange things are afoot @mhodges. Found an answer, but it wasn't what I thought. Thanks for your suggestion.