# Why does this jquery.inArray not work for a simple string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

So following on from [the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515705/how-do-i-access-a-javascript-value-across-functions-variables/), why does `jquery.inArray` not work in this example? Having linked the IP address to the tax rate array, the code should check if a country is in the array (and therefore subject to one of the taxes). If not, set the tax rate to 0.

Same array:

```
var taxes_from_database = new Array();
  taxes_from_database["BE"]=27.7;
  taxes_from_database["ES"]=25.0;
  taxes_from_database["GB"]=23.5;
  …
```

Then:

```
if(jQuery.inArray("ES", taxes_from_database) != -1) {
console.log("is in array");
} else {
console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

Running it in the browser, when the string is "ES" (or "25.0"), which *is* in the array, as you can see, the console returns "is NOT in array". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you JJJ, you were quickest.

Comment: OK @JJJ. Editing it.

Comment: Array's entries has to be indexed based. Here you are trying to put key instead of numbers. You can do it via javascript object `{}` instead of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used it wrong.You cannot have array with indexes such as `BE`,`ES`,etc.

You have to use `hasOwnProperty` and `associative` array,like this: `var taxes_from_database = {};`.

```js
var taxes_from_database = {};
  taxes_from_database["BE"]=27.7;
  taxes_from_database["ES"]=25.0;
  taxes_from_database["GB"]=23.5;
if(taxes_from_database.hasOwnProperty('ES')){
    console.log('is in array'); 
}
else{
    console.log('is NOT in array');  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How you created array is a wrong way, because in your case you need an `associative` array(you are trying to put key instead of numbers). Please take a look here:

```js
var taxes_from_database = new Array();
  taxes_from_database["BE"]=27.7;
  taxes_from_database["ES"]=25.0;
  taxes_from_database["GB"]=23.5;

console.log(taxes_from_database);

var taxes_from_database = {};
  taxes_from_database["BE"]=27.7;
  taxes_from_database["ES"]=25.0;
  taxes_from_database["GB"]=23.5;

console.log(taxes_from_database);
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandru, that's great. JS is not my strong point.

Comment: @MatthewBennett, You're welcome ! don't forget to accept my answer if you consider the best in order to help other people.

Comment: Yes. I was just waiting for the time to tick down before accepting it. Thank you.

Comment: WIth pleasure .